# How can I solved KeyError: "None of [Index(['lymphoid_neoplasm'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

This code line:

```
gen_histogram = df.loc[1, ['lymphoid_neoplasm']]
```

gives a error like **KeyError: "None of [Index(['lymphoid_neoplasm'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"**

All code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("CosmicMutantExportCensus.tsv", sep = '\t')

primary_histology = df['Primary histology']
gen_histogram = df.loc[1, ['lymphoid_neoplasm']]
id_sample = df["ID_sample"]
# print(df["Primary histology"])

diseases = []
for i in primary_histology:
   if i in diseases:
      continue
  else:
      diseases.append(i)
# print(diseases, "\n", len(diseases), "farklı hastalık vardır.")

ids = []
for j in id_sample:
   if j in ids:
      j+=1
   else:
      ids.append(j)
 # print(ids, "\n", len(ids), " farklı Doku Id'si vardır.")
 # print(gen_histogram)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you want to get the `'lymphoid_neoplasm'` column value of the first row, you should use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[0, n]
```

where `n` is the position of `'lymphoid_neoplasm'` column

Comment: Thank you. But it gives a error like this : ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types